# JTable копирование выделенных ячеек в clipboard

Tags: java, jtable

Коллеги, прошу помочь с копированием выделенных ячеек в буфер обмена вместо CTRL+C - по правому щелчку мыши и выборе **Copy**. В настоящий момент я могу скопировать в буфер только одну ячейку, с которой начинал выделение. Вся область не копируется (с CTRL+C конечно копируется, но хочется понять как это сделать в Java).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас код выглядит так:

```
JMenuItem menuCopy = new JMenuItem("Copy");
menuCopy.addActionListener(e -> {
    String cellValue = table.getModel().getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), table.getSelectedColumn()).toString();
    StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(cellValue);
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(stringSelection, stringSelection);
});
popup.add(menuCopy);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это было нелегко:

```
JMenuItem menuCopy = new JMenuItem("Copy");
menuCopy.addActionListener(e -> {
    Clipboard clipboard;
    StringSelection stsel;
    StringBuilder sbf = new StringBuilder();

    final int numcols = table.getSelectedColumnCount();
    final int numrows = table.getSelectedRowCount();
    final int[] rowsselected = table.getSelectedRows();
    final int[] colsselected = table.getSelectedColumns();

    for (int i = 0; i < numrows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < numcols; j++) {
            sbf.append(table.getValueAt(rowsselected[i], colsselected[j]));
            if (j < numcols - 1) {
                sbf.append('\t');
            }
        }
        sbf.append('\n');
    }
    stsel = new StringSelection(sbf.toString());
    clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    clipboard.setContents(stsel, stsel);
});
popup.add(menuCopy);
```